# using ≠ like != pros/cons

Tags: php, equality

Is it ok to use `≠` instead of `!=`. I know it's an extra alt code and I've never used this on a project but I've tested it out and it works. Are there any pros/cons besides having to `Alt +8800`.

Edit:
I'm not going to use this, I just want to know.
Tested language php.

Comment: Which programming language are we talking about?

Comment: When is pressing `Alt +8800` any easier than `!=` in any language?

Comment: Edited. @Tony I know it's not easy and not necessary.

Comment: Just don't. Never, ever.

Comment: It works??? Who would've thought... +1 for sharing this arcane knowledge o_O

Comment: @mingos: it does not seem to work on my system (see my edit)

Comment: This is not a valid PHP operator.

Comment: @thkala: shame. It would be fun to see the faces of my teammates when reading code with such an unorthodox thing :D.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You have not mentioned which programming language your question is about, but `≠` has a number of disadvantages:

- It does not exist in ASCII. Code written in anything else but pure 7-bit ASCII is way too vulnerable to strange encoding errors and it forces unnecessary requirements upon the editing program. It might even be displayed incorrectly depending on the editor font etc, and you do *NOT* want that to happen when editing code.
- Even if it does work, it is not widely used, which by itself is a good reason to avoid it.
- It saves screen space, sure, at the expense of clarity. It might even be mistaken for an `=` if you are tired. Terse code is not always best.
- It cannot be typed easily in a portable manner. As a matter of fact, I don't know how to produce it on my Linux system without a graphical character selector.

Except for the screen space (disk space is actually the same or worse than `!=`) I cannot think of any other "advantage", so why bother?

EDIT:

On my system (Mandriva Linux 2010.1) with PHP 5.3.4 the `≠` (U+2260, or 8800 in decimal) operator **does not work**. Are you certain that your editor does not implicitly convert it to `!=`?

Comment: Why bother? Because it is a valid math character the same as ≤ & ≥ instead of <= and >=. That matched with less code characters (I type =` to print) to build working code.